# Code design for many different inputs but similar execution (output)

Tags: java, csv, design-patterns

I have converter that converts CSV  and writes it to database (always the same tables). There are many possible inputs and each input needs another configuration for CSV, as column name mappings, or restrictions on data. Of course some code parts are identical: as loop over all data rows or writing in database.

What is a good code pattern or design pattern(s) for such situation with many different possible inputs?

**EDIT**: One idea would be to use Dependency Injection pattern and create relevant different code parts in Factories. What do you think about it ? The used programming language is Java.

Comment: I think this question is a little too broad for stack overflow. Perhaps looking at [ask] to narrow it down a bit would be a good idea. I would suggest though - stop using CSV and instead look to JSON/XML which allow you to more dynamically structure your data.

Comment: Showing some of your code could elicit more specific answers, but in general, I'd think you'd want a factory that returns the appropriate strategy for a given input and supplies it to a template that contains the repetitive code.